# Ngrx Effects with multiple actions

Tags: ngrx, ngrx-effects

How can I add an action right before http request? I want to run TEST_INC before request... and TEST_DEC after http request

```
 @Effect()
 acadDomain$: Observable<Action> = this.actions$.pipe(
  ofType('INIT_ACADEMY_DOMAIN'),
  // I want here to apply action "TEST_INC"
  mergeMap((action: any) =>
     this.http.get('https://DOMAIN/settings.json').pipe(
        switchMap((data) => [
           { type: 'INIT_ACADEMY', payload: data },
           { type: 'TEST_DEC' }
        ])
     )
  )
);
```

FYI: (rxjs 6)

Comment: Why would you want do achieve with this?

Comment: `tap(() => this.store.dispatch({ type: 'INIT_ACADEMY_DOMAIN' })`. this is not best practice. Think about the design and see if you can avoid this. IE: What happens if the http request fails? Now you need to revert it.